# Image not adding to pug file

Tags: image, web, pug

I am adding an image to the home.pug. When a home.pug is opened on localhost, the image does not show on the browser. How do I fix it?

```
div.banner
     img(src="/img/p1.png")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YD7y.png)

Answer (score 0):

How is your `static` directory exported?

You might have to use:

```
div.banner
     img(src="/static/img/p1.png")
```